# Writing SQL Query, Separating One Columns Into two columns with filter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am not db administrator and now i am facing a problem with the querying single table.

i got the table as follow

updated

[image]

I wan to make a query to come out like the following picture

updated

[image]

How can i do it? quite noob for query thanks.

Comment: Describe, with words, how to combine the input rows to get the output rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT MAX(T1.CloseDate) as [Date],
       T1.Job,
       MAX(CASE WHEN T1.WorkRole = 'Case' THEN COALESCE(T2.WorkType,T1.WorkType) END) AS [Case],
       MAX(CASE WHEN T1.WorkRole = 'Engineer' THEN COALESCE(T1.WorkType,T2.WorkType) END) AS [WT]
FROM TableName T1 LEFT JOIN
     TableName T2 ON T1.CloseDate<T2.CloseDate AND T1.Job=T2.Job 
GROUP BY T1.Job
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Result:

```
Date                        Job     Case    WT
------------------------------------------------------
January, 01 2008 00:00:00   Senior  Normal  Electronic
January, 01 2005 00:00:00   Junior  Average Electronic
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3a27/13).

Comment: Hi Bro Raging Bull, Now i updated my picture. I tested with your code and it is working. later i will accept as answer and add credit. i want worktype normal rather than urgent for senior. because Normal closedate is latest. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @DartfrogImi: I have updated my answer with a self join to bring the latest case ("normal").

Answer (score 0):

That is called `pivoting`.  One way to do it:

```
select  CloseDate as [Date]
,       Job
,       max(case WorkRole when 'Case' then WorkType end) as [Case]
,       max(case WorkRole when 'Engineer' then WorkType end) as WT
from    YourTable
group by
        CloseDate
,       Job
```

Comment: Isn't this wrong to group by CloseDate? In this case will return 3 rows, instead of 2 as expected, as in question I see grouped by Job only.

Comment: Yep, it retrun 3 rows. 
Hi   Stanislovas Kalašnikovas,
Now i updated my picture.  i want worktype normal rather than urgent for senior. because Normal closedate is latest. Thanks for any advice.